# Probem with Master Detail Page when i use FormsAppCompatActivity for Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail

I want the toolbar is still displayed when i navigating from the master detail.

**My project:**

[image: My project]

**What I want:**

[image: what I want]

Comment: The screen in _what you want_ sounds like a manual implementation of fragment transition that ***seems*** a master detail page... I'm not an android expert, so I'm not sure, but you will have to get your hands dirty to do it with [tag:xamarin.forms]

Comment: Which code have you tried?